# iPhone: string resource not resolved

Tags: iphone, string, resources

preemptive sorry for the newbie question.

I'm trying to load strings from a resource file in an iPhone project (XCode, Objective C++). I've created a file called s.strings with the following content:

```
/* 
   s.strings
   Created by Seva on 11/22/09.
*/
"a"="b"
```

The file is in UTF-16, it's in the Resources folder in the project, XCode treats it as "text.plist.strings". There are no localizations to this file.

Then I'm trying to load that string on application start:

```
NSString *s = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"a", @"s", nil);
```

No matter what I do, the value of s is "a", as opposed to "b".

I must be missing something very basic - any ideas, please, what's wrong in this trivial example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each statement in the strings file needs to be terminated with a semicolon (;).

Comment: Thanks, that was it.

Hoping for a resource compilation error message was a vestige of prior Windows experience, I take it. Mac is far too user-friendly for such nastiness.

Comment: That's strange, I usually do get compilation errors if I miss a semicolon in the strings file.